# Does the onClick event in react have priorities while choosing? If yes, how do you change them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I have the following JSX code

```
<div onClick={() => this.props.callFunction()}>
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <MyComponent1 />
<div>
```

If I put the on click event in `h2` tag, it works fine, but If i put it in the `div` tag outside it or the `MyComponent1` tag, it does not work. Is it because 'MyComponent` already has a onClick inside it?

EDIT:
`App.js`

```
render()
{
    return(
        <div className="flex-container" style={{"position":"absolute", "width":"90.5%","top":"57px", "right":"0px", "flex": "1","display":"flex"}}>
          <div className="widget" onClick={() => { this.props.viewComponent("project") }}>
            <h2>Project Details</h2>
            <ProjectWidget/>  
          </div>
          <div className="widget" onClick={() => { this.props.viewComponent("resource") }}>
            <h2>Resource Details</h2>
            <ResourceWidget/>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`ProjectWidget`

```
return (
        <div>
            {!isLoading ? (
                <div>
                    <ReactDataGrid
                        columns={this._columns}
                        rowGetter={rowGetter}
                        rowsCount={data.length}
                    />
                </div>
            )
                : (
                    <p>Loading...</p>
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour has very little to do with React but more with Javascript itself. Events Propogation follows three phases,

- Capture
- Target
- Bubbling

Now in react events written like `onClick` are triggered on target and bubbled up. If you want to make use of capture phase, you would specify the event like `onClickCapture` i.e appending `Capture` as suffix to the event.

Now in your case,

```
<div onClick={() => this.props.callFunction()}>
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <MyComponent1 />
<div>
```

onClick is specified on div and hence if you click in Heading 1, the onClick event will be triggered on `h2` and bubbled up to `div` where it will be captured.

Now suppose you Click on the area occupied by `MyComponent1` which as you mention has a onClick specified within the component, the event will be captured by the div within `MyComponent1` that has the handled specified on it and unless you `stopPropagation` in the this event handler, the event will be propagated to the the parent div where it will be caught.

Now looking at the third case, where you specify the onClick on `MyComponent1` like

```
<MyComponent1 onClick={() => this.props.callFunction()}/>
```

Here onClick in not a handler on `MyComponent1`, but is passed as a prop to the Component and unless you make use of it in the Component to assign to the top level div, this handler wouldn't ever work

You handler needs to be used like

```
render() {
   return (
      <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>P{/* rest content */}</div>
   )
}
```

Comment: The first case you have mentioned, the outer div one, I still can't seem to get the onClick to work for <MyComponent1>. It only works for <h2>. However, I just noticed that it's working on click and drag. Strange?

Comment: Unless you specify `<div onClick={this.props.onClick}>P{/* rest content */}</div>` in the MyComponent, onClick on MyComponent1 like `<MyComponent1 onClick={() => this.props.callFunction()}/>` won't work. Also you need to show MyComponent1 code if I have to provide more details

Comment: But I don't want `<MyComponent1 onClick={() => this.props.callFunction()}/>`.  I want to have a single onClick() in the outer div tag

Comment: @SamarthJuneja, in your case ReactDataGrid component might be capturing the click event and stopping its propagation, can you please check it

Comment: ReactDatGrid is a node_module. Say it stops the propogation, how to override it?

Answer (score 0):

I made a small demo in CodeSandbox, while trying to replicate your case. For me, the clicks are working in all three cases, namely Div, H1 and CustomComponent.

Have a look right here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jz5qzonjjv